# ListBox SelectedItem issue. Showing Overridden ToString instead

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I have encountered an issue trying to get the `SelectedItem` in a `ListBox`. The `Listbox` is datasource bound to the list further down my example.

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "StringPosition";
listBox1.ValueMember = "StringPosition";
listBox1.DataSource = MatchList;

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(curItem);
}
```

When i run the program and select an item in the list rather than the `MessaseBox` showing the `SelectedItem` it shows the overridden `ToString` method in my custom class. Now the custom `ToString` method was just a leftover from the MSDN example and i don't actually need it. However even if i comment it out rather than the overridden `ToString` it will simply display `Parser.SectorBodies` which is my project namespace and the custom class. So how do i resolve this so i can get the selected item in my `ListBox`

```
static List<SectorBodies> MatchList = new List<SectorBodies>();

public class SectorBodies
{
    public int MatchCount { get; set; }
    public string StringPosition { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemFileComment { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemX { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemY { get; set; }
    public string SolarSystemZ { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
     return
     "   Position: " + StringPosition +
     "   Count: " + MatchCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to show?  The selecteditem is going to be an object since you are using them as a datasource

Comment: @Plutonix I was trying to get the text of the selected item so i can evaluate it

Comment: Not very clear question. Did you mean this: `SectorBodies curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as SectorBodies; MessageBox.Show(curItem.ToString());`?

Comment: @Sakura I'm sorry if its not clear. i honestly didnt know how to make it any more clearer which is my inexperience. However it would seem i missed something very simple that Vivek below noticed. I try not to ask to many questions and do like to work it out for myself but sometimes i am just stumped

Comment: Can you comment an example string you expect to get by `MessageBox`?

Comment: @Sakura Thank you for your time however Vivek has solved my issue below. I appreciate the effort though. Sorry i wasn't able to articulate my problem better i'm sill a newb! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should rather do this. I did not get the time to test it but the SelectedValue should be string only so there should not be any need to do a ToString().

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string curItem = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(curItem);
}
```

To show everything I'd try this as pointed out in one of the comments too. You can grab the entire object, cast it to your class. Then you have access to all what's in the object. Hope this works!

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SectorBodies curItem = listBox1.SelectedItem as SectorBodies;
        MessageBox.Show(curItem.StringPosition);
    }
```

Comment: SelectedItem does not have an argument .Value However i suspect you meant string curItem = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString(); which does work. I dont know why i never saw that :)

Comment: Just updated my answer. Are you looking for text / displaymember value?

Comment: Thanks for your input. This helps a lot i am kinda frustrated i couldn't figure this out on my own. Been reading a lot of articles on this.